# Evaluating constant expressions in clang tools

Tags: clang, clang++

I'm writing a Clang tool and I'm trying to figure out how to evaluate a string literal given access to the program's AST. Given the following program:

```
class DHolder { 
public:
  DHolder(std::string s) {}
};

DHolder x("foo");
```

I have the following code in the Clang tool:

```
const CXXConstructExpr *ctor = ... // constructs `x` above
const Expr *expr = ctor->getArg(0); // the "foo" expression
???
```

How can I get from the `Expr` representing the `"foo"` string literal to an actual C++ string in my tool? I've tried to do something like:

```
// From ExprConstant.cpp
Evaluate(result, info, expr);
```

but I don't know how to initialize the `result` and `info` parameters.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but I ran into this a moment ago when I could not use `stringLiteral()` to bind to any arguments (the code is not C++11).  For example, I have a `CXXMMemberCallExpr`:

```
addProperty(object, char*, char*, ...); // has 7 arguments, N=[0,6]
```

The AST dump shows that ahead of the `StringLiteral` is a `CXXBindTemporaryExpr`.  So in order for my memberCallExpr query to bind using `hasArgument(N,expr())`, I wrapped my query with `bindTemporaryExpr()` (shown here on separate lines for readability):

```
memberCallExpr(
    hasArgument(6, bindTemporaryExpr( 
        hasDescendant(stringLiteral().bind("argument"))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is to use the AST matchers to match the string literal and bind a name to it so it can be later referenced, like this:

```
StatementMatcher m = 
    constructExpr(hasArgument(0, stringLiteral().bind("myLiteral"))).bind("myCtor");
```

and then in the match callback do this:

```
const CXXConstructExpr *ctor = 
    result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXConstructExpr("optionMatcher");

const StringLiteral *optNameLiteral = 
    result.Nodes.getNodeAs<StringLiteral>("optName");
```

The literal can then be accessed through

```
optNameLiteral->getString().str();
```